# Variable Persistence in Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm making a domino game and when the user adds a domino to the left, the domino is added but when the function exits the domino added is GONE.

FYI:

- fitxesJoc (Link List) contains the dominoes of
  the game and is a pointer passed to the function (so that it lasts all the game)
- opcionesCorrectas (Domino) contains the correct choices of domino

  - inferior (int) contains the smaller number of the domino
  - superior (int) contains the bigger number of the domino
  - pos (int) the position of the domino
- opcionFitxa (int) contains the choice of the player
- ultimaFitxa->seg is the 'next' node

```
tNode* ultimaFitxa = (tNode *)malloc(sizeof(tNode));
ultimaFitxa->info.inferior = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].inferior;
ultimaFitxa->info.superior = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].superior;
ultimaFitxa->info.pos = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].pos;
ultimaFitxa->seg = fitxesJoc;
fitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;
```

Header of the function

```
unsigned int demanar_fitxa_tirar(tJugador *jugador, tNode* fitxesJoc, tPartida *partida, tPila* fitxesBarrejades, bool primerCop)
```

Call of the function

```
resultado = demanar_fitxa_tirar(&Jugadors[jugadorActual], fitxesJoc, partida, fitxesBarrejades, true);
```

This way I add the domino, in the top of the other dominoes.

Comment: I don't see a question in here.  Hint: Questions usually end in a question-mark "?".

Comment: This is really hard to understand because the code isn't in English.

Comment: Post the function that adds a new LL entry so we can see the SCOPE!

Comment: Publicar el código más (just in case)

Comment: LOL @rlbond:  No code is in English. :)  Its in code, which is why it's called Code.  Non-English variable names shouldn't be any barrier to understanding code.

Comment: @abelenky , any variable that long and bumpy are hard to read!

Comment: Well, i prefer a "listWithThisOrThat" to "a" or "listaConTisOTat" :)

Comment: Bordering on xenophobic here :P

Comment: @abelenky: Then I assume you can understand obfuscated C just fine? Meaningful variable names are a core tenant of good programming because they serve as self-documenting code. Code in a foreign language is as bad as code in which every variable name is only one letter.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the extra code - I think it confirms what most of the answers are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the last line of `demanar_fitxa_tirar`:

```
fitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;
```

is assigning to a local variable, which has no effect on the calling code.  You need to pass a pointer to the calling code's `fitxesJoc`, like this:

```
unsigned int demanar_fitxa_tirar(..., tNode** fitxesJoc, ...)  // Note extra *
{
    // ...
    *fitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;                                  // Note extra *
}

void mainProgram()
{
    tNode* fitxesJoc;
    // ...
    resultado = demanar_fitxa_tirar(..., &fitxesJoc, ...);     // Note extra &
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @ Richie, *shakes fist* ... Although your answer is superior so ... +1

Comment: @Aiden: A whole 37 seconds in it this time - you're slipping!  8-)

Comment: @Richie: Off my game today. And my answer is shit :P *goes for coffee*

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it's not clear where your function starts and ends and what it takes as parameters but I *guess* your problem is with the `fitxesJoc` variable which is probably passed as an argument to the function. C copies arguments when calling functions (call-by-value). You could pass the address to `fitxesJoc` variable using a pointer instead and rewrite it as something like this:

```
// fitxesJoc would be a `tNode**` rather than `tNode*`.
tNode* ultimaFitxa = (tNode *)malloc(sizeof(tNode));
ultimaFitxa->info.inferior = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].inferior;
ultimaFitxa->info.superior = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].superior;
ultimaFitxa->info.pos = opcionesCorrectas[opcionFitxa - 1].pos;
ultimaFitxa->seg = *fitxesJoc;
*fitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've provided enough code, but I suspect the problem is in:

```
fitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;
```

(Linked-list now equals the new Node).

The problem is that parameters are passed by value.
If you want to change the value of the parameter, you'll need to pass by pointer,
and use the pointer to change the value.

```
*pfitxesJoc = ultimaFitxa;
```

Please provide more code, including the function header and the function call, for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually adding the new domino to the linked list. But, it's hard to tell because you need to post more code, and because your code isn't in English.